# List of SharePoint 2010 Out-of-Box Web Parts

Tags: 2010, web-part, out-of-the-box

Can anyone provide me with a nice URL where it will show all the Out-of-Box web parts in SharePoint 2010 and what each one of them can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

SharePoint Server 2010 OOTB web Parts

http://blog.sharepointedutech.com/2010/03/21/sharepoint-server-2010-ootb-web-parts/

SharePoint Foundation OOTB Web Parts

http://blog.sharepointedutech.com/2010/03/20/sharepoint-foundation-ootb-web-parts/

Answer (score 6):

I refer you to the [list provided by WonderLaura](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157-7d96-4e15-a987-54b8a3e4d948&ID=44). It was built based on the beta version, but I don't think anything was added in the SP2010 RTM.

You will also find more information about each web part if you go to the web part gallery for your site collection. Click on the web part name to see a page with a brief description and a preview (or you could modify the list view for the web part gallery to include the description). You may need to activate certain features to bring some web parts into the gallery if they are missing. You'll still have to Bingle<sup>TM</sup> if you need more documentation on each one.

Comment: Yeah I also saw this one, kinda need something with more explanation on each Web Part.

Comment: Added another one with a bit more info.

Comment: ...then discovered the information is actually in the web part definition and accessible through the web part gallery (slaps forehead).